# MongoDriver Deserialization

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a issue with MongoDriver. I have a inherited class from Class1 a mongo repository for Class1. For example:

```
public class Class1: EntityBase
{
    [BsonElement("a")]
    public A Attr { get; set; } 
}

public class Class2: Class1
{
    [BsonElement("d")]
    public IList<float> D{ get; set; }

    [BsonElement("p")]
    public int P{ get; set; }

    [BsonElement("s")]
    public int S{ get; set; }
}
```

And I have a several projects in my solution. I have project with repositories where the classes are located. When I try to insert and load a Class2 instance in a first project so everything's fine. But when I try to do same thing in the other:

```
Element 'd' does not match any field or property of class Class1.
```

Both projects refers to the repository project (dll). What can be wrong?

Comment: Try adding `[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]` on `Class1`.

Comment: I fix my issue with `[BsonKnownTypes]` attribute on `Class1`. The reason why it works in one project and not in the other one is simple. The working one uses the inherited type, so it register it. Second project don't and cannot deserialize to unknown type.

Comment: Glad you were able to resolve it! Can you post an answer to your own question so that others that may have the same problem can more easily see how you fixed it?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solotuion. `Class1` should have mongo attribute `[BsonKnownTypes]`

So `Class1` should looks like:

```
[BsonKnownTypes(typeof(Class2))]
public class Class1: EntityBase
{
    [BsonElement("a")]
    public A Attr { get; set; } 
}
```

The reason why one project works and the other one throws exception was simple. The first one usel `Class2` and inserts an instance to repository so mongoDriver register inherited type. After that it was able to deserialized the stored instance to `Class2`. The second one had no idea about `Class2` so it tried to deserialized object to `Class1` and it throwed the exception about uknown element 'd'.